# pg_ksp is extremely memory intensive for k>1

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am using `pg_ksp` (from the pg_routing extension for postgis) on a subset of the OpenStreetMap database with 400.000 nodes, if I set `k=1` to find the best path the query takes about a second and around 100 MB of RAM

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_ksp('SELECT gid as id, source, target, cost FROM ways',12,7,1)
```

If I set `k=2` or greater the ram usage skyrockets to 16 GB crashing my pc before even returning any result.

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_ksp('SELECT gid as id, source, target, cost FROM ways',12,7,2)
```

Am I using the command `pgr_ksp` incorrectly or is this drastic difference between `k=1` and `k=2` expected (if so why?) ?

Comment: According to wikipedia, the space complexity of the Yen algorithm is N^2 + KN, while the time complexity is O(KN(M + N log N)), where k is the number of paths, N nodes, and M edges. It would appear that both are linear in K, so it is hard to see how this could produce the results you are seeing. Sadly, I don't have OSM loaded currently, so can't check, and I don't have time to study the implementation of the algorithm myself.